# Aligning two div's next to each other in a div horizontally

Tags: html, css

Got an issue at the moment. The pink box below is inside a section. Currently it is:
[image]

```
section {
    height: 341px;
    background: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both; }

.vid {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    text-align: center;
    background: pink;
    height:300px;
    width:656px; }
```

**AS PER REQUEST FOR HTML**:

```
<section>
        Section
        <div class="vid">
        <div class="image1">
</section>
```

Each time I attempt to add another image beside it of a different width, nothing really appears. Trying to make it have the same spacing etc as the left side did as-well (so the gap between the purple left side and the pinks starting side).

Any tips? The new class will be named image1 .

Comment: Provide your HTML code also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aligning two divs side by side horizontally, you need to add width to both divs and add `display: inline-block;`.

Here is an example:

```css
section {
  height: 341px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

.vid {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image1{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="vid">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="image1">
    Div 2
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did a little test below and it should work fine. Right now the boxes are centered in the section (as it was in your code but not in your picture). If you wish to align to the left, change text-align to left.

```css
section {
    background: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

.vid {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 24px 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    text-align: center;
    background: pink;
    height:300px;
}

#image0{
    width:256px;
}
#image1{
    width:256px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <section>
    <div id="image0" class="vid"></div>
    <div id="image1" class="vid"></div>
  </section>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used the other persons method and it worked. Thank you very much for assisting as-well!

Answer (score 0):

Your html markup would be usefull in order to understand your problem thoroughly. However, if I understand you correctly, you would like to have the image positioned in the same line as the `.vid` element.

In that case, the problem is that you need to add `display: inline-block` propety to your `.vid` element. It allows an element to have width and height, but in every other respect treats it like an inline object (such as for instance `span`).

Moreover, it seems that you may have `overflow: hidden` property specified on the `section` element or one of its parents, because otherwise your image should display below the section.

Basicaly your `css` could go something like that:

```
section {
    height: 341px;
    background: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both; }

.vid {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    text-align: center;
    background: pink;
    height:300px;
    width:656px;}
```

You can try it on this [pen](http://codepen.io/sztal/pen/YqZpeL)